# Disable horizontal scroll bar in material-ui's Drawer component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I do not want my drawer to scroll right and left, but cannot get it to go away. In the Menu and MenuItems I've tried setting max-width/width to 100%, and box-sizing to border-box. Also `overflow: hidden` on the Drawer itself. Any ideas? I believe it the MenuItem's padding that causes the scroll to appear.

```
            <Drawer
                docked={false}
                onRequestChange={(drawerOpen) => this.setState({ drawerOpen })}
                open={this.state.drawerOpen}>
                <Menu>
                    <MenuItem
                        containerElement={<Link to="/" />}
                        primaryText="Home"
                    />
                </Menu>
                <BottomMenu>
                    <MenuItem
                        containerElement={<Link to="/asd" />}
                        primaryText="asd"
                    />
                </BottomMenu>
            </Drawer>
```

Comment: instead of using `%` have you tried with `vw`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, looks the same as `%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by turning off autoWidth on my Menu elements

```
                <Menu
                    autoWidth={false}
                >
```

ref: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/menu